# Convert a hex string to base64 in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to convert a hex string to base64 in Julia. I looked at [Codecs.jl](https://github.com/BioJulia/Codecs.jl) but I am not sure if that will help me.

The hex string I want to convert is `49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d`.

Not really sure where to start here so any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you want to use `Base64` from the standard library. First use `hex2bytes` to convert your string to a byte array, then `base64encode` to convert it back to a  string:

```
using Base64
function base16to64(st::AbstractString)
    bytes = hex2bytes(st)
    return base64encode(bytes)
end
```

Comment: to go from a Base64 string to a hex string, `bytes2hex(base64decode(base64string))`